# CakePHP and Facebook Plugin: read user checkins

Tags: facebook, cakephp, facebook-graph-api, checkin

I am using CakePHP and Nick Baker's Facebook Plugin, and I am trying to retrieve a certain user's checkins. The problem is that I have quite no idea on how to do this. There is nothing related to checkins in the plugin's documentation. All I have is the `api()` method which I don't know how to use.

I have this so far:

```
App::import('Lib', 'Facebook.FB');
$FB = new FB();
$this->set('checkins', $FB->api('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->Connect->user('id').'/checkins'));
```

but the `checkins` variable contains only this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => https://graph.facebook.com/1000005215732xx/checkins
)
```

But have no idea on how to continue. Also, after I retrieve the checkins, I would like to search whether a user has checked in in a specified place.
I will be glad for any help you can give! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `api()` method only takes a URL relative to the API endpoint, so you should be calling:

```
$result = $FB->api('/<uid>/checkins');
```

Also, make sure you have the [proper permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), especially `user_checkins`.

Comment: Oh, so that was it. Managed to get it going. Thanks. And regarding the other issue? How can I search my checkins? I have tried `$this->set('checkins', $FB->api('/search?type=checkin'));` but it brings an empty array. In the FB documentation, it says: `https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`, but I believe the access token is automatically added like in all other requests made by the plugin? If not, how can I retrieve it and add it to the request? Thanks!

Comment: You're right, the access token should be added automatically, but I believe you have to actually pass a search term to `/search` using a `q=` parameter.

Comment: I thought about this also, but what should the `q=` parameter contain? Place name, location, checkin message? I tried with a location which should have returned something, but there was no response (not even that empty array). Here is the FB documentation about the checkins, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/ , but I don't see anything extra in the search section...

Comment: You're right, not very clear at all. If you're getting an empty array off of that it's possible you don't have `user_checkins` permission - can you verify that you have that permission?

Comment: Sorry for the delay of my response. Yes, I have that permission. I added it in the `perms` array, and even accepted it in my last login.

Comment: Oh darn, for some reason my 'test' checkin has not been posted; that's why the array was empty. I tried again now and my checkin is returned. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out.